# Provider won't let me change nameserver

Tags: provider, nameservers

I just bought a domain on which I would like to host many subdomains. The easiest way to do that is to change the nameserver for this domain and check just host yourown nameserver. So I tried to change the nameserver for my domain. The hoster just tells me that I'm not able to change the nameserver for my domain. Why? Are they even allowed to do that? I though they have to give you access to the complete domain, for me that includes changing ther nameservers.

Thanks

Marc

Comment: Where did you purchase your domain?

Comment: Strato, is a german hoster